# Is there a way to get next value for the same key in the next dictionary in the list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two different lists of dictionaries, `list_a` and `list_b`. First list of dictionaries holds nucleotide sites and the other list of dictionaries has start and end coordinates of all genes. If the site falls into the range of the gene coordinates than that site belongs to that gene. However sometimes even though a site is outside the range it is still belongs to that gene. E.g the site from `list_a`, second dictionary - 8 belongs to the `gene_b`.

```
list_a = [{'Ch': 'I', 'name': 'test_1', 'site': 2}, {'Ch': 'II', 'name': 'test_2', 'site': 8}, {'Ch': 'II', 'name': 'test_3', 'site': 10}]

list_b = [{'Ch': 'I', 'name': 'gene_a', 'start': 1, 'end': 3}, {'Ch': 'II', 'name': 'gene_b', 'start': 3, 'end': 6}]
```

Here is first part that work fine.

```
for item_a in list_a:
    for item_b in list_b:
        if item_a['Ch'] == item_b['Ch'] and item_a['site'] >= item_b['start'] and item_a['site'] <= item_b['end']:
            print item_b['name'], item_a['site']
```

So I want to have some thing like this

```
if item_a['site'] >= item_b['start'] and item_a['site'] >= item_b['end']
and item_a['site'] <= the next site in the next dictionary in list_a... 
or the beginning of the next gene in the next dictionary... ???
```

(i have figured out how to order list of dictionaries by keys)

I tried to utilise the `next()` function, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: All `Ch` are unique in list_b?

Comment: No there are six different chromosomes, I, II, III, IV, V, X in both lists actually. I have to check for Chromosomes to equals in two lists. Thanks

Comment: Your sample `gene_b` *ends* at `6`; so site `8` wouldn't match, would it?

Comment: That's right. That is the problem. How to match the site that doesn't fall into the range..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more efficient method would be to parse out the sections into a structure *per* `Ch` value, in sorted order:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import bisect

ranges = defaultdict(list)
for info in list_b:
    bisect.insort(ranges[info['Ch']], (info['start'], info['end'], info['name']))
```

The `bisect.insort()` call inserts new entries in sorted order into the list, saving you another sorting loop.

Now use this to home in on the ranges given a `list_a` `Ch` value:

```
for gene in list_a:
    for start, stop, name in ranges[gene['Ch']]:
        if start <= gene['site'] <= stop:
            print name, gene['site']
            break
```

This still doesn't search for a next match against the 'stop' parameter, of course, but the latter loop *can* be folded into a generator expression, suitable for use in the `next()` function, and because the ranges are sorted, you can continue the search for the next site name:

```
for gene in list_a:
    site = gene['site']
    range = iter(ranges[gene['Ch']])
    # skip anything with start > site
    name = previous = next((name for start, stop, name in range if start <= site), None)

    # search on for a matching stop, looking ahead. If we find a stop < site
    # the previous entry matched. If we ran of the end of our options, the last
    # entry matched.
    for start, stop, name  in range:
        if site > stop:
            previous = name
            continue
        if start > site:
            name = previous
        break

    print name, site
```

The `range` iterable 'remembers' where the first `next()` search stopped, we can loop over it to continue searching for a suitable `stop` value in from that point.

Note that presumably the `stop` values are *always* going to be equal or larger than the `start` values; there is no point in testing against the next item `start` values as well; if `site <= stop` is `True` then `site <= start` is *also* `True`.

Comment: it gives me SyntaxErro at name, stop = next((name, stop for ..?

Comment: @user2753377: sorry, fixed that; the first expression tuple must use parenthesis here.

Comment: This is awesome man, thanks so much for help. I spend all day trying to get it to work. And I haven't seen python like that before. Cheers

Comment: Hey Martijn, sorry to bother you again. I am trying to use your code, but hard to follow. The three site I have 5, 25 and 105 and the following start/ends pairs 1-20, 30-45, 70-100. Only 25 site matches to the correct name, two other don't match to any names - None...Thanks

Comment: @Serine: what does `ranges[...]` show for that `Ch` value? The `5` site should certainly match. The `105` site shouldn't match anything, should it?

Comment: ranges[..] looks good to me. its a dictionary with Ch as keys where each value is a list of tuples, where each tuple holds start, stop and name. I wanted 105 to match to 70-100 range if it doesn't fall into the next range e.g 110-160...

Comment: @Serine: right, I may have misunderstood that part; I've updated the code to handle that part; `105` will now print the name for the `70-100` range because the `site` value falls before `start`.

Comment: @Serine: Not sure why the `5` site doesn't match however, without seeing the exact contents of the `range[gene['Ch']]` structure.

Comment: there is a bug somewhere or I'm doing something wrong. `print ranges` `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'I': [(1, 20, 'gene_a')], 'II': [(30, 45, 'gene_b'), (70, 100, 'gene_c'), (110, 160, 'gene_d')]})`. `print next(range)` doesn't print `gene_c` or `d`. `print name, stop` also only prints `gene_a` and `gene_b`. For some reason `next()` doesn't step through to `gene_c` and `d`. overall scripts prints out `gene_a 5`, `None 25` and `gene_b 105`. p.s the idea is awesome it would be great if we can get it to work. Thanks

Comment: @Serine: Right; adjusted again. Now the `next()` call *only* serves to skip any entries whose start value is too high; the real work is done in the while loop to 'look ahead' by remembering the previous name from iteration to iteration.

Comment: The code work beautifully,thanks heaps. The data set is large and complex. I need also to search against the `start` value, because some peaks actually can lie just before the `start` value. I have segregated data into two lists. I just need to have a separate loop through that different subset of data. I have your previous answers saved. Was your previous loop searching against the `start` value? where `name, stop = next((..` and `if name and site <=stop:` following `else:` and nested `if site < start:`? Your magical `next()` function is hard to grasp. much appreciate your help

Comment: @Serine: In that case, just use `range[0]`; the first range, and check if the `start` value is close enough. Don't muck with iteration for that edgecase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do something more straightforward.

In list_b you could add a new key called site: which you could set to (start+end)/2.

Then merge list_a and list_b, and sort them by the key (Ch:, site:) in sorted_list.

Then go though sorted_list one at a time. If it's a gene (from list_a) skip it and keep track of its name: and if it's a site (from list_b) set its name to the previous item's name: or use the name: you saved.

There may be some tweaking of "what is closest" to do, but i'm sure you can do it with looking ahead and behind your current position and doing some appropriate business logic.